# Can t connect iPhone anymore to my virtualbox after update iOS

Tags: iphone, macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I wanted to start learning about mobile development and learned Swift and install macOS in virtualbox.

Everything worked just fine, I could use Xcode, deploy my app on my iPhone(iOS 14.1) and use it.

After I update my iPhone to 14.4 iOS it seems that I can t connect anymore to macOS.

My iPhone is recognized on host system(Windows 10) but when I try to access it in virtualbox it seems that it try but can t connect.

I tried with other cables and with my iPad(iOS 14.4) but I think that with the new update I can t connect anymore.

I have a macOS Catalina on virtualbox

I thinking about try and get Mac OS Big Sur and try or moving to VMware
If u have any suggestions to repair this I’m opened